# Redirect every page on example.com to example.org

Tags: .htaccess

I'm wanting every page of www.example.com to redirect to www.example.org

I'm using the following .htaccess in the root of example.com

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

if I navigate to www.example.com, I'm redirected to www.example.org - that's great

If I navigate to www.example.com/example.php I get a 404 from example.com

Edit: Cloudflare was caching files, the accepted answer as well as the method in the question work to redirect files to the appropriate page. If using Cloudflare, turn OFF caching by turning on development mode when in development

Comment: What's the full message in the error log? might be simpler juat to do `Redirect / http://www.example.org/`

Comment: for whatever reason, my host is pushing back on giving me the apache logs, and can't seem to tell me why this redirect isn't working. I suspect theres something else they don't want me to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this 1:1 rewrite:

> `RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
>   RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Actually the `L` flag is not required. The rewriting process ends immediately anyway in case of an _external_ redirection for obvious reasons...

Comment: Thanks, this should also work but isn't. I'm thinking there's something funky with the host and/or server configuration, but they won't let me get into the logs for whatever reason

Comment: It turns out it was due to cloudflare caching - the redirect works either way